# Why does "new CultureInfo("xx")" throw an exception in one environment but not in another?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, globalization

My Asp.Net MVC application targets .Net Framework 4.6.1

In my dev environment, this works:

```
var x = new CultureInfo("xx")
```

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.4210.0
(I got this info from a random error page, elsewhere in the same MVC application, it's mentioned at the bottom)

IIS 10.0.18362.650 on Windows 10 build 18363.1016
(info gotten from IIS manager - help - about)

On a hosted staging (and live) environment, the same code throws an exception

```
[CultureNotFoundException: Culture is not supported.
Parameter name: name
xx is an invalid culture identifier.]
   System.Globalization.CultureInfo..ctor(String name, Boolean useUserOverride) +230
```

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.3928.0
IIS 8.5.9600.16384 on Windows Server 2012 R2

I'm aware that "xx" isn't a valid culture (I just used it to compare resources files in different languages, and needed a non existing culture). But what I want to know is why this fails on one environment and works on another. The asp.net versions are (almost) the same.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/70f01bf8-290b-43e3-a2ae-08870220c3c8/cultureinfogetcultureinfo-behavior-change-on-windows-10?forum=netfxbcl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is happen is when you create a culture with name like "aaa" which
> is is not one of the names carried by Windows, at that time Windows
> will try to create it for us and try to fill the culture properties as
> much it can by matching the language part and country part. for
> example, if I try to create ja-US which I think not exist, Windows
> will try to fake the culture by getting the language information from
> the Japanese language and will get the country information from US and
> combine it into a new culture. now when passing "aaa" which not
> matching any language/country, Windows will just use Invariant culture
> properties for that. And that is what you are seeing.
>
> This is the behavior defined by Windows starting Windows 10 and not
> really the .NET. the framework just calling the OS for getting the
> needed information. the code of CreateSpecificCulture is just calling
> the OS at the end.

[Source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30725#issuecomment-526779604)

Comment: And apparently Windows Server 2012 behaves differently then?

Comment: @fre_der yes, Windows Server 2012 is "based" on Windows 8, so I think that the same behavior (observed in Windows 10) could be observed on Windows Server 2016 (given the fact that it is "based" on Windows 10)